# Alternatives to enum like functionality and able to extend in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, enums, frameworks

I was implementing a framework internally(in company) in which application should work based on a Type provided. I was planning to implement that Type to be as enum. But developers who are trying to customize that functionality should be able to extend the Type and able to add more options to it. Since we cannot extend enum to add more cases, I was looking for an alternative.

Comment: Maybe an [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) type could be an alternative (can be extended with more options/static members). Although instances can then be created that contain several options (/"cases", in this context), not necessarily just a single one. Another alternative is simply using a structure type with static data members as types.

Comment: thanks @dfri OptionSet  doesn't work in my case as it allows only Int and in my case I should be able to read the value in some cases, so I'm going with the second option you have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom `struct` as an extendable identifier without making it an `OptionSet` simply by conforming to `RawRepresentable` manually, as follows. This also has the useful side-effect of meaning that the user cannot pass arrays of the value as if they were a single instance of the value itself, which is not desirable if you want uniqueness. Here's how I handle unique identifiers:

```
public struct Identifier: RawRepresentable, Hashable {
    public typealias RawValue = String
    public let rawValue: RawValue
    public init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return rawValue.hashValue
    }

    static let unknown = Identifier(rawValue: "Unknown")
}
```

With this in place, the user can extend the structure with more static variables as follows:

```
extension Identifier {
    static let item1 = Identifier(rawValue: "Item 1")!
    static let item2 = Identifier(rawValue: "Item 2")!
    static let item3 = Identifier(rawValue: "Item 3")!
}
```

Comment: N.B. I'm conforming to Hashable as well, since my own code frequently uses Identifiers of this type as keys in dictionary structures.

Answer (score 1):

How about a protocol with a static var like [`PreferenceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey), [`LayoutValueKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layoutvaluekey), [`AlignmentID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alignmentid) etc.

```
protocol LayoutValueKey {
    static var defaultValue: Self.Value
    associatedtype Value
}
```

Used as follows:

```
private struct Flexibility: LayoutValueKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
}
```

Btw another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996006/what-is-the-name-of-this-technique-pattern) was asking what's the name of this pattern?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the implication of the pattern.