# What is the name of this technique/pattern?

Tags: swift, swiftui, types

#### What is the name of this technique/pattern?

I notice that this pattern shows up quite frequently in the Swift world but I don't know what its name is.

1. define a new type that conforms to a protocol
2. solely use the new type as a unique value to create a new "thing"

```swift
extension VerticalAlignment {
    struct CustomAlignment: AlignmentID {...}

    static let customAlignment = VerticalAlignment(CustomAlignment.self)
}
```

#### Define a new `LayoutValueKey` type only for passing layout value

```swift
private struct Flexibility: LayoutValueKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
}

extension View {
    func layoutFlexibility(_ value: CGFloat?) -> some View {
        layoutValue(key: Flexibility.self, value: value)
    }
}
```

#### Define a new `PreferenceKey`  type only for passing preference value

```swift
struct NavigationBarTitleKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: String = ""
    ...
}

extension View {
    func navigationBarTitle(_ title: String) -> some View {
        self.preference(key: NavigationBarTitleKey.self, value: title)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's plain polymorphism. You declare an abstraction, and use concrete types to fulfil that abstraction. In most cases there's more than one type conforming to the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

These three examples share a number of specific characteristics:

1. “Protocol conformance” – One defines a custom type that conforms to a particular [protocol](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/extensions#Nested-Types) (e.g., in the case of `VerticalAlignment`, it accepts a custom type that conforms to the `AlignmentID` protocol, etc.).
2. In all three of these protocols ([`AlignmentID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/alignmentid), [`LayoutValueKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layoutvaluekey), and [`PreferenceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey)), the protocol only has a single requirement, `defaultValue`.
3. In all three examples, the protocol’s only requirement, `defaultValue`, is `static`.
4. When you implement your own custom type conforming to the respective protocol, you supply the type (not an instance of that type), to the relevant API. E.g., you supply an `AlignmentID` type to a [`VerticalAlignment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/verticalalignment) or a [`HorizontalAlignment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/horizontalalignment), a `LayoutValueKey` to [`layoutValue(key:value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/layoutvalue(key:value:)), a `PreferenceKey` to [`preference(key:value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/preference(key:value:)) or [`transformPreference(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/transformpreference(_:_:)), etc. The interface only requires a type, not an instance, because the three respective protocols only have `static` requirements.
5. In the case of `VerticalAlignment` example, this `AlignmentID` type is a “[nested type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/extensions#Nested-Types)” (and is used when that type bears no utility outside of the context of the type in which it is nested).

But, the specific combination of the above (namely an interface/protocol with only static requirements, which is then subsequently used solely as a type) does not have a well-established name. It entails a combination of more general patterns (e.g., an “abstraction pattern”, abstracting the implementation details; a “compositional pattern”, building complex behaviors from smaller, simpler components; etc.), but might be best considered a SwiftUI “convention” than a specific, named “pattern”.

Comment: I just added some examples, can you take a look at it again?

Comment: @ThaiD.V. – I’ve expanded my answer because I previously focused on the “nested type” aspect of the `AlignmentID`, but your new examples don’t use nested types.